# Как в javafx прописывать код для кнопок?

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Только перехожу от консоли к графическому интерфейсу, в связи с этим возник вопрос:
Есть код, который к примеру, считывает данные с клавиатуры с помощью трёх верхних текстовых ячеек, после нажатия на клавишу "вычислить" выполняет какое-то действие. Допустим перемножает все три введённых значения между собой и возводит получившееся число в квадрат, результат записывается в нижней текстовой панели.
Как это сделать в консоли я знаю, но как заставить программу делать это с графическим интерфейсом javafx?

[image: графический интерфейс]

Comment: https://devcolibri.com/javafx-2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-button/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде Batton нужно создать переменную private TextField result (над этой строкой необходимо прописать @FXML), предварительно в файле sample.fxml, прописать fx:id="result" в строке <"TextField>, чтобы получилось <"TextField fx:id="result"> ("result" - имя переменной). Далее, в методе, отвечающим за выполнения кода Batton присвоить переменную "result" нужной переменной, например:

```
String str = String.valueOf(result.getText());
double h = Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
 int a = Integer.parseInt(result.getText());
 int b = Integer.parseInt(result.getText());
```

Вывод выглядит примерно так:

```
int c = a+b;
result.setText(String.valueOf(c));
```